# Remap Scroll Lock to lock Windows (Win+L)

Tags: windows-7, autohotkey

I'm trying to re-purpose some keys that I never use into functions I use all the time.  I discovered AutoHotkey here on SuperUser and figured this would be the way to go, but I'm having difficulties already.

The first thing I wanted to do is to remap the Scroll Lock key so that it locks my computer (like pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> does).  From what I have gathered in the AutoHotkey help file, this should work

```
SCROLLLOCK::Send #l
```

but it doesn't do anything.

If I change the script to read `SCROLLLOCK::Send #e` then the Scroll Lock key does launch Windows Explorer, as would be expected.  Does anyone know how to lock the computer from AutoHotkey?

---

**Update -**
I tried the following code as well, but to no avail:

```
SCROLLLOCK::Run C:Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

The command does lock the computer if you just dump it in the run command, but in AutoHotkey it just does a really brief flash of the "waiting" cursor, then nothing.

Comment: You also appear to be missing a backslash in your run command - `C:Windows` => `C:\Windows`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can lock the computer with AutoHotkey's [Run](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) command:

```
ScrollLock::Run, % "rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation"
```

You have to be careful when passing parameters, so I like to use an [expression](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Variables) to encode the entire command properly.